# Google Maps API - loading directions panel automatically and setting center

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Need some help with my Google Map. I'm using ASP to dynamically set the start and end variables for my map (enters the customers postcode). I have two questions really:

1 - How do I change the map center depending on the customer?

2 - How can I get the map to load both the map and directions upon the page loading?

Thanks in advance.

```
<body>
  <div id="floating-panel" >
      <strong>Start:</strong>
      <input id="start" value="<%postcode1%>"/>
      <br>
      <strong>End:</strong>
      <input id="end" value="<%postcode2%>"/>
    </div>
    <div id="right-panel"></div>
    <div id="map"></div>
<script>

    function initMap() {
        var directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService;
        var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 7,
            center: { lat: 41.85, lng: -87.65 } //don't want to always use these co-ordinates
        });
        directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
        directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('right-panel'));

        var control = document.getElementById('floating-panel');
        control.style.display = 'block';
        map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(control);

        var onChangeHandler = function () {
            calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay);
        };
        document.getElementById('start').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
        document.getElementById('end').addEventListener('change', onChangeHandler);
    }

    function calculateAndDisplayRoute(directionsService, directionsDisplay) {
        var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
        var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
        directionsService.route({
            origin: start,
            destination: end,
            travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
        }, function (response, status) {
            if (status === google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
                directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            } else {
                window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
            }
        });
    }

</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=<%=mapkey %>&signed_in=true&callback=initMap"
    async defer></script>
```

Comment: How do you know what the center should be based on the customer?

Answer (score 1):

You asked:

> 2 - How can I get the map to load both the map and directions upon the page loading?

Call `calculateAndDisplayRoute` at the end of `initMap`

[proof of concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8dpLsr6j/)

Comment: You've made me the happiest man. So simple/obvious too, thanks.